# does nhibernate 3 have any problem with saving byte []

Tags: nhibernate

in my mvc project im using nhibernate 3 as orm, but i have a problem with saving and loading images which their type is byte []

```
public class PersonImage  : PersistentObject
{
    private string _contentType;
    private byte[] _image;

    private Person _person;


    virtual public string ContentType
    {
        get { return _contentType; }
        set
        {
            if ( value != null && value.Length > 20)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid value for ContentType", value, value.ToString());
            _contentType = value;
        }
    }

    virtual public byte[] Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set { _image = value; }
    }

     }



 public class PersonImageMap : ClassMap<PersonImage>
{
    public PersonImageMap()
    {
        Schema("personnel");

        Id(p => p.Id);

        Map(p => p.Image)
            .CustomSqlType("varbinary(MAX)")
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(p => p.ContentType)
            .Not.Nullable();

        }
```

}

the problem is that i think this image cant be saved correctly because when i  load it i just can see a part of image not the whole image!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found it
the length attribute should be defined in this case

```
 Map(p => p.Image)
            .Length(2147483647)
            .CustomSqlType("varbinary(MAX)")
            .Not.Nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully mapped images (Tablet PC InkPicture control contents) using NHibernate 2.1 so it should certainly work in 3. The properties are byte arrays and the database fields are varbinary(max), but I do not add any additional methods to the mapping:

```
Map(p => p.Image);
```

That's it. My suspicion is that you are saving and retrieving the entire image but it is being cropped in the UI somehow.

Comment: i am totally sure that its a bug in nh3, because i was working with nh2 and i didnt have any problem with MAP(p=> p.Image),, but as long as migration to nh3 this problem exists and i resolved it by adding length attribute