# NHibernate: validate schema with byte[] property

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need to validate schema where I have one object with byte[] property (BLOB). When I run validation I receive OverflowException: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."

I'm using NHibernate 3.1.0.400 with FluentNHibernate 1.2.0.712
I have created test project to check that. Here is the code (it falls while validating):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

        string connectionString = "some connection string";
        Console.WriteLine("Running test with connection string: {0}", connectionString);
        Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                               {
                                                   {"connection.provider", "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"},
                                                   {"connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver"},
                                                   {"connection.connection_string", connectionString},
                                                   {"dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect"},
                                               };
        configuration.AddProperties(props);
        var mappings = Fluently.Configure(configuration)
            .Mappings(m => m
                               .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<DataResource>()
                               .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<DataResource>());

        var sessionFactory = mappings
               .ExposeConfiguration(DoExtendedConfiguration)
               .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void DoExtendedConfiguration(Configuration configuration)
    {
        SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(configuration).SetDelimiter(";").SetOutputFile("schema.sql");
        schemaExport.Create(false, true);

        SchemaValidator schemaValidator = new SchemaValidator(configuration);
        schemaValidator.Validate();
    }

 public class DataResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Value { get; set; }
}
public class DataResourceMap : ClassMap<DataResource>
{
    public DataResourceMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works OK in MS SQL, it creates a VARBINARY(8000) column. You could try explicitly setting a large length for the value field as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4723020/43846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any mention about such bug on officials, but after I updated FluentNhibernate and Nhibernate to the last available version (via Nuget), the issue resolved. That suites me, so I will close the question as if nobody finds any other solution and stack allow me to do that.